# Error while creating object using parameterized constructor in Java

Tags: java, class, oop, object

I'm getting below error when creating object along with parameterized constructor.

> Main.java:6: error: constructor Cipher in class Cipher cannot be
>   applied to given types

```
Cipher cy = new Cipher(k);              ^
```

required: no arguments

found: int

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Here is my files looks like

```
<b>Main.java</b>

public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args){
   int k=8;
      Cipher cy = new Cipher(k);
      String encrypted_msg = cy.encrypt(message);
      String decrypted_msg = cy.decrypt(encrypted_msg);
      view1.displayResult("Decrypted message: "+decrypted_msg);
        }
    }

<b>Cipher.java</b>

import java.util.*;
public class Cipher
    {
    private int key;
    // Constructor 
    public void Cipher(int k)
        {
        key = k; 
        }// end Constructor 

    } // end class
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
public void Cipher(int k)
```

to

```
public Cipher(int k)
```

With a return type of `void`, that is not a constructor.  In Java, a constructor does not specify a return type.  The return type is simply the name of the class.

So in your example, because you have not defined a constructor, Java will provide a default no-argument constructor of the following format:

```
public Cipher() {}
```

thus the error message is telling you that only a no-argument constructor exists, but you are calling a constructor that expects an `int` argument.

Comment: Thanks. It did worked pretty well. I'm not a frequent user of Java. But this looks quite interesting. Java is a piece of work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
<b>Cipher.java</b>

import java.util.*;
public class Cipher
    {
    private int key;
    public Cipher(int k) //remove the void
        {
        this.key = k; //use this for object level reference
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Please add some text as to how your post answers the question, and what the original author can do. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.